# ASP.NET - how can I recompile the language resources?

Tags: asp.net, resources

I notice that if I have another language in my project and change the HTML content file it will work on my computer but if I upload to the server it keeps the **old** HTML.

It seems to work if I modify the .resx resource file even if I don't make any changes, just add a space for example, then save, then upload also.

Why is this? I'm guessing that the HTML is cached somewhere, more importantly how can I upload a large batch of updated translations, without having to modify each .resx file??? I have a lot of Japanese

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

But .resx files needs to be compiled. That is why only upload doesn't work.

Comment: well I did a recycle and I changed a .cs file to force a rebuild, but still doesn't work. What do I need to do to recompile?

Comment: look at bin folder, try to clean it.

Comment: clean it, how? please help!

Comment: just remove all files in bin folder. I'am not sure that your site is recompiled

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27831/discussion-between-garath-and-happygilmore)

Answer (score 0):

I just completed a project translating an existing site into several languages.

I did this using webforms with c# codebehind. Hope my answers can assist you...

I used RESX files to store the different language translations (index.aspx.fr-CA.resx for example) and in the c# code behind you would have to use 'protect override void InitializeCulture()' method to have the RESX files come into play. Do you have this setup?

I found it easily for me to create the multiple languages as such -- I would generate the local resource (after tagging the static content in  tags) and then copy that generated RESX file, paste and rename it to the other language.  The RESX file is an XML and in the VS it creates an easy to edit table view to copy and paste translated languages (or alternatively you can use tools such as RESX Manager -see link below). What I did, to keep it convenient to edit the syntax of different languages and modify, was take my existing content text and run it through Google or Bing translator and paste the translated text into the RESX files...

If your looking for something that will automatically translate your site for you and then re displays in an iframe, you can look into Bing Translation API http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/using-the-free-bing-translation-apis  but in my case, this was not ideal as the translations would not take into account the syntax of different languages and you can not go in and edit after someone that speaks and is familiar with sites in that language tells you that it makes no sense! =P

Also this tool is very helpful if you already have existing RESX files and you will need to  modify an  section on one language, you can edit in the others easily.  http://resxmanager.com/  its free for non-commercial use. It's easy to setup and can definitely safe you time when you get going.